# Windows / PHP open local folder on intranet website

Tags: php, windows, intranet, microsoft-file-explorer

IE11 allows us to open a local folder in explorer with a hyperlink. Unfortunately with FireFox and Chrome this doesnt work anymore. Because of security issues.

We have a network drive `\\host\folder` mapped to a local disc `Z:\`

Is there another way to make a link on a intranet website (PHP/Symfony) which opens a explorer window with the folder opened?

Comment: Have you tried a URL (e.g. `file://path/to/file`) instead of a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) ?

Comment: Yes, tried that. firefox requests are made with file://///path/to/file however. no luck